# Login for GoogleApiClient inside Service

Tags: android, google-plus, google-cloud-storage, google-api-client, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to implement `GoogleApiClient` inside a service.

```
   public class SGoogle extends Service implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    //...
    @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
            setConnected(false);
            if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                // show the localized error dialog.
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
                return;
            }
            try {
                result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

But obvoiusly, it is needed to use `Activity` for functions:
`GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog` and `result.startResolutionForResult`. Is there any method to avoid such interaction? Or may be some examples to avoid interaction with connection to a Service using namely `Activity`? Does somebody solved such problem?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320303/android-how-to-resolve-google-api-connection-fail-from-a-service/31394676#31394676) may be helpful.

Comment: @qbix ,10x i was looking namely for this answer.